# How do I know if a BigQuery job was queued?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery jobs will get queued if there are no available slots. This is clearly stated at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots#query_execution_under_slot_resource_economy

> If a query requests more slots than currently available, BigQuery queues up individual units of work and waits for slots to become available. As progress on query execution is made, and as slots free up, these queued up units of work get dynamically picked up for execution.
>
> BigQuery can request any number of slots for a particular stage of a query. The number of slots requested is not related to the amount of capacity you purchase, but rather an indication of the most optimal parallelization factor chosen by BigQuery for that stage. Units of work queue up and get executed as slots become available.
>
> When query demands exceed slots you committed to, you are not charged for additional slots, and you are not charged for additional on-demand rates. Your individual units of work simply queue up.

Is it possible to discover if a job stage was queued and if so, how long for?

I've taken a look at [BigQuery > Documentation > Reference > JOBS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) but didn't spot anything there might answer these questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_TIMELINE_BY_*` data if you have Admin access. The query results contain one row for every second of execution of every BigQuery job. There will be a column called `STATE`, and if it has a value of `PENDING` at any time during the job it was queued (for interactive queries).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-timeline